# Styling for responsive behaviour

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm sure this is baby stuff for many, but I'm afraid I just can't get it right. The more I tweak, the further away I get with the results.  No need to describe the consequences of my efforts.  Instead here is the desired effect as the viewport shrinks:

[image: Full div layout and desired layout when viewed on smaller screen]

The lower image is NOT what I'm actually producing; it's what I'd like to happen.  Instead I've got the elements doing everything but this, the most annoying being the text wrapping under the images.

If someone can point me toward the most efficient code for this, including media queries, I'm grateful.

Comment: We cannot know what code have you tried to point you in the correct way. Try to post some code so we can reproduce the effect that you are getting.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with media queries and hoped that would be understood. The issue is not so much how to designate  the split on items 2 and 3.  It's keeping the left text margin uniform and not allowing it to wrap under the images (the numbered grey boxes).  Obviously when the screen is smaller, the paragraphs are taller.  Thus the lowest lines will wrap all the way to the left side of the container unless I add a large margin under the image.

Comment: BTW, I think I can achieve this simple quest.  What I don't want is a huge stylesheet with all kinds of band-aid fixes to lead to more fixes.  And that's what I have now.  It's just not semantic and it can't possibly be the shortest route.

Answer (score 0):

I trust you're using `@media` queries in your CSS, so I'll assume this unless told otherwise.

One way you could look at it is this:

Set the `display` property to `inline-block` of the Items 2 & 3.

Then, set the `width` of items 2 & 3 to 50% when the viewport is at more than 600px (desktop/tablet) wide. This will make them sit side-by-side.

*Note: you might need to use `box-sizing: border-box;` for this to work properly; depending if you're using borders or not.*

Then, on your media query for less than 600px (for mobile), set Items 2 & 3's `width`s to `100%` to fill the width of the screen.

This will make them cascade neatly underneath one another.

Furthermore, I would recommend looking at using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) as this makes responsive website coding a doddle.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the eassier solution here is using `media queries`. I give you a bit of background, just in case you don't know what they are.

When you create a stylesheet, the styles created are applied to the elements you target using selectors, like class, ids, etc.

`Media queries`allow you to set conditions to that CSS rules, for example, you can create rules depending on the screen size.

See this fiddle to check how it works.

```css
.short {
  width: 50%;
  float: left
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .short {
    width: 100%;
    float:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum elementum purus vel purus tempor, id lobortis sem placerat. Phasellus sed magna varius, fermentum velit sed, vestibulum ante. In enim est, iaculis in neque sed, dictum venenatis nulla.
  Fusce sit amet auctor augue. Vestibulum at dui ipsum. Sed vehicula bibendum eros sed feugiat. Fusce cursus mi non eros eleifend, viverra tempus massa accumsan. Maecenas venenatis purus sit amet metus ornare, at feugiat ex bibendum. Aliquam erat volutpat.
  Vivamus tristique odio non elit imperdiet, vel ornare diam suscipit. Pellentesque ultrices, tortor vitae varius vehicula, metus mi porta est, tincidunt posuere lorem turpis non justo. Nulla ullamcorper dolor a mattis ornare.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum elementum purus vel purus tempor, id lobortis sem placerat. Phasellus sed magna varius, fermentum velit sed, vestibulum ante. In enim est, iaculis in neque sed, dictum venenatis nulla.
  Fusce sit amet auctor augue. Vestibulum at dui ipsum. Sed vehicula bibendum eros sed feugiat. Fusce cursus mi non eros eleifend, viverra tempus massa accumsan. Maecenas venenatis purus sit amet metus ornare, at feugiat ex bibendum. Aliquam erat volutpat.
  Vivamus tristique odio non elit imperdiet, vel ornare diam suscipit. Pellentesque ultrices, tortor vitae varius vehicula, metus mi porta est, tincidunt posuere lorem turpis non justo. Nulla ullamcorper dolor a mattis ornare.
</p>
<p class="short">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum elementum purus vel purus tempor, id lobortis sem placerat. Phasellus sed magna varius, fermentum velit sed, vestibulum ante. In enim est, iaculis in neque sed, dictum venenatis nulla.
  Fusce sit amet auctor augue. Vestibulum at dui ipsum. Sed vehicula bibendum eros sed feugiat. Fusce cursus mi non eros eleifend, viverra tempus massa accumsan. Maecenas venenatis purus sit amet metus ornare, at feugiat ex bibendum. Aliquam erat volutpat.
  Vivamus tristique odio non elit imperdiet, vel ornare diam suscipit. Pellentesque ultrices, tortor vitae varius vehicula, metus mi porta est, tincidunt posuere lorem turpis non justo. Nulla ullamcorper dolor a mattis ornare.
</p>
<p class="short">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum elementum purus vel purus tempor, id lobortis sem placerat. Phasellus sed magna varius, fermentum velit sed, vestibulum ante. In enim est, iaculis in neque sed, dictum venenatis nulla.
  Fusce sit amet auctor augue. Vestibulum at dui ipsum. Sed vehicula bibendum eros sed feugiat. Fusce cursus mi non eros eleifend, viverra tempus massa accumsan. Maecenas venenatis purus sit amet metus ornare, at feugiat ex bibendum. Aliquam erat volutpat.
  Vivamus tristique odio non elit imperdiet, vel ornare diam suscipit. Pellentesque ultrices, tortor vitae varius vehicula, metus mi porta est, tincidunt posuere lorem turpis non justo. Nulla ullamcorper dolor a mattis ornare.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum elementum purus vel purus tempor, id lobortis sem placerat. Phasellus sed magna varius, fermentum velit sed, vestibulum ante. In enim est, iaculis in neque sed, dictum venenatis nulla.
  Fusce sit amet auctor augue. Vestibulum at dui ipsum. Sed vehicula bibendum eros sed feugiat. Fusce cursus mi non eros eleifend, viverra tempus massa accumsan. Maecenas venenatis purus sit amet metus ornare, at feugiat ex bibendum. Aliquam erat volutpat.
  Vivamus tristique odio non elit imperdiet, vel ornare diam suscipit. Pellentesque ultrices, tortor vitae varius vehicula, metus mi porta est, tincidunt posuere lorem turpis non justo. Nulla ullamcorper dolor a mattis ornare.
</p>
```

The CSS is easy. The first thing is the class `short`, which applies always to the elements. Then you find the `media query` which says that the CSS rules that encloses are applied only when the `width` is under `500px`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a project on responsive webpage and I'm a new learner so it's all basics:

https://github.com/nirupaboricha/Responsive_Webpage

Let me know if it's helpful.